# Mathematica shorthand for mapping function over two lists simultaneously

Tags: list-manipulation

I am still relatively new to Mathematica, so please bear with my question. I have the following statement that works perfectly well:

```
Table[findcvec[phif, phit, v1[[i]], v2[[i]], +1], {i, Length[v1]}]
```

where `v1` and `v2` are two lists of the same length.

EDIT: I had `phif` and `phit` as scalar numbers in mind, but the answer below also treats the case where they could be lists.

Now, I would like to make a Mathematica shorthand version of this statement using `#`, `&`, `@`, etc. But this attempt failed:

```
findcvec[phif, phit, #[[1]], #[[2]], +1]] &/@ Join[v1,v2]
```

After scouring through several stackexchange posts, I realised that I should be trying `MapThread`. But the following approach also failed:

```
MapThread[findcvec[phif, phit, #1, #2, +1]] & {v1, v2}
```

Could someone please tell me the correct way of doing this?

This might be a duplicate, but I couldn't any previous question that addresses this specifically. Thank you!

Comment: `MapThread[findcvec[phif, phit, #1, #2, +1]&, {v1, v2}]`?

Comment: `Thread[findcvec[phif, phit, #1, #2, 1]] & @@ {v1, v2}`

Comment: are the lengths of  `v1` and `v2` same?

Comment: @kglr Yes, they are.

Comment: then both MassDefect's and ciao's suggestions should work.

Comment: you can also use  `MapThread[findcvec[phif, phit, #1, #2, 1] &]@ {v1, v2}` and `Inner[findcvec[phif, phit, #1, #2, 1] &, v1, v2,   List]`.

Comment: @MassDefect Your method gives the error `MapThread[findcvec[phif,phit,#1,#2,+1]]&,{vec1,vec2}\" is incomplete; more input is needed.`

Comment: @kglr Yes, `MapThread[findcvec[phif, phit, #1, #2, 1] &]@ {v1, v2}` works perfectly! Thank you! Would you like to post this as an answer? Or post it myself?

Comment: The code of @MassDefect works for me.  The code the [OP shows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239939/mathematica-shorthand-for-mapping-function-over-two-lists-simultaneously#comment605778_239939) is not copied correctly.

Comment: `MapThread` does not have an operator form shortcut like `Map[func]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, I am extremely sorry, I had misplaced my `[]`'s. MassDefect's response works perfectly for me as well.

Comment: No problem. Just wanted to point out there was a typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `phif` and `phit` are not lists, then MassDefect's and ciao's suggestions in comments as well as variations of them work:

```
ClearAll[v1, v2, a, b,  phif, x]
v1 = Array[a, 3];
v2 = Array[b, 3];
phif = x;

result1 = Table[findcvec[phif, phit, v1[[i]], v2[[i]], +1], {i, Length[v1]}]
```

> ```
> {findcvec[phif, phit, a[1], b[1], 1], 
>  findcvec[phif, phit, a[2], b[2], 1], 
>  findcvec[phif, phit, a[3], b[3], 1]}
> ```

```
result2 = MapThread[findcvec[phif, phit, #1, #2, 1] &, {v1, v2}]; 
   (* MassDefect's comment *)

result3 = Thread[findcvec[phif, phit, #1, #2, 1]] & @@ {v1, v2};  
  (* ciao's comment *)

result2b = MapThread[findcvec[phif, phit, #1, #2, 1] &]@{v1, v2};

result3b = Thread[findcvec[phif, phit, #1, #2, 1] & @@ {v1, v2}];

result3c = Thread[findcvec[phif, phit, v1, v2, 1]];

result4 = Inner[findcvec[phif, phit, #1, #2, 1] &, v1, v2, List];

result5 = findcvec[phif, phit, #1, #2, 1] & @@@ Transpose[{v1, v2}];

result1 == result2 == result2b == result3 == result3b == result3c == 
  result4 == result5
```

> ```
> True
> ```

If either of `phif` and `phit`(say, `phif`) is a list then we need to modify the methods with `Thread` to use second and third arguments to specify what to thread on:

```
phif = {x, y, z};
result1 = Table[findcvec[phif, phit, v1[[i]], v2[[i]], +1], {i, Length[v1]}]
```

> ```
> {findcvec[{x, y, z}, phit, a[1], b[1], 1], 
>  findcvec[{x, y, z}, phit, a[2], b[2], 1], 
>  findcvec[{x, y, z}, phit, a[3], b[3], 1]}
> ```

```
result2 = MapThread[findcvec[phif, phit, #1, #2, 1] &, {v1, v2}]; 
  (* MassDefect's comment *)

result3 = Thread[findcvec[phif, phit, #1, #2, 1], List, {3, 4}] & @@ {v1,  v2};  
 (* ciao's comment *)

result2b = MapThread[findcvec[phif, phit, #1, #2, 1] &]@{v1, v2};

result3b = Thread[findcvec[phif, phit, #1, #2, 1] & @@ {v1, v2}, List, {3, 4}];

result3c = Thread[findcvec[phif, phit, v1, v2, 1], List, {3, 4}];

result4 = Inner[findcvec[phif, phit, #1, #2, 1] &, v1, v2, List];

result5 = findcvec[phif, phit, #1, #2, 1] & @@@ Transpose[{v1, v2}];

result1 == result2 == result2b == result3 == result3b == result3c == 
  result4 == result5
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thank you, that was a very enlightening answer. It helped me understand the functioning of `Thread` and `MapThread`.

Comment: I had `phif` and `phit` as just scalar numbers when I posted the question. I will specify this in the post.